# Adding a Row to an Excel Table

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto, listobject

I am working on an Excel 2013/2015 VSTO workbook application. From data entered in a Windows form I'd like to create a new record in an existing Table on one of my worksheets.

How do I insert a new Table row into an Excel Table (not a simple worksheet array) using C# and VSTO?

Comment: Record a macro of you doing it manually, translate into the interop methods most of which are the same.

Comment: I realized my mistake. It should be possible to get the `ListObject.ListRows.Add` method in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace. I got confused because a similar type exists in `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` but is missing the `Add`method. Working on it. What I'm struggling with now is getting the `ListObject` handle for the table.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for fixing the typos. Had to undo one but the rest is OK.

Comment: OK, English orthography vs. forum guidelines. Don't know how to decide. I'll obey if I have to.  :)

Comment: @AlexK. OK, problem solved. You kept me on the right track. It boils down to IntelliSense not showing the available members and me confusing the namespaces. The `ListObject` in `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` can indeed be used. It does have an `ListRows` property from `Interop`, which provides the needed `Add()` method. Intellisense did not show it. The solution was right there, and I didn't see it. Would you like to write your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sounds like your own answer would be more helpful to others than mine, you can answer your own question then accept it.

Comment: OK, just wanted to ask before I take the credit that should be yours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject` provides the needed functionality. The table can be referenced and rows added as follows:

```
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject lo = Globals.Sheet1.MyTable;
lo.ListRows.Add();
```

Optionally, the position of the new row can be specified (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.listrows.add.aspx). Default is at the end of the table.

IntelliSense did not show the `Add()` function in my case, which caused the confusion. Just type it in.

Comment: How strange. Can anyone explain why this doesn't appear in intellisense? What a terrible gotcha. WHY, MICROSOFT? WHY?!